Read/write query routing in AWS Aurora Postgres
Is there a way or tool which can help route read and write queries to their respective instances in Aurora Postgres cluster, I got to know about ProxySQL but can it be used with Aurora Postgres?

Found a solution using Spring's TransactionRoutingDataSource, looks promising but yet to try. Dropping the link here - https://medium.com/javarevisited/read-write-in-different-db-instances-java-spring-a43bf18a5c77

One more post explaining solution using same TransactionRoutingDataSource - https://vladmihalcea.com/read-write-read-only-transaction-routing-spring/

AWS Aurora (postgres or mysql) will provide you the writer and reader endpoint  by default when you create a cluster and have atleast one reader and writer nodes.
if you have access to the console, click on the database instance -> connectivity & security --> endpoints section , you would see 2 entries, i.e. writer and reader endpoint. And these endpoints remain static when there is a failover or new nodes being added so the applications can use it without changing them in case of underlying nodes changes.
Note that in case of multiple reader nodes , the reader endpoint will connect to reader nodes in round robin fashion.
sample doc to refer : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.Connecting.html

not sure why there was downvote for it , or what was the expectation here ?

I didnt downvote but with your suggestion do I have to keep two connections, one for each reader and writer endpoint?

yes my suggestion was to make use of the reader and writer endpoints individually as 2 different connections , now i understand that you would like to route your write queries to writer node and select type queries to reader node , yes then proxy sql will be handy here , where in i have a instance hosting the proxy sql, added these 2 endpoints as sql server list and add rules to route the writes and reads to the respective nodes. this link will be a starter for you : https://proxysql.com/documentation/aws-aurora-configuration/  @MAlok
